# jQuery DataTables ir até uma página

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Preciso adicinar no meu jQuery DataTable uma função para que o usuário diga que quer ir atá a página 9 e ele seja redirecionado. Usei a seguinte função:

```js
$('#btnIrAtePag').on('click', function () {
    var table = $('#grid').DataTable();
    table.page($('#txtIrAtePag').val() - 1).draw(false);
});
```

Porém queria adicionar os o botão e o input ao lado da paginação e não estou conseguindo. Existe alguma outra forma de fazer essa função?

Comment: Cara a pergunta está um pouco confusa. Deixa ver se compreendí. Queres adicionar um input onde o utilizador vai introduzir o número da página que quer ir, certo?

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo, @CristianoGilbertoJoão

Comment: E queres adicionar o input como se fosse recurso do DataTable?

Comment: Se possível sim, @CristianoGilbertoJoão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, resolvi da seguinte forma. Adicionei o parametro initComplete do datatables e adicionei os elementos que eu queria..

```js
initComplete: function () {
                var criaDivElementos = "<div class=\"pull-left\">";
                criaDivElementos += "<div class=\"input-group\">";
                criaDivElementos += "<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtIrAtePag\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Ir até a página..\">";
                criaDivElementos += "<span class=\"input-group-btn\">";
                criaDivElementos += "<input type=\"button\" id=\"btnIrAtePag\" class=\"btn btn-default\" value=\"Ir!\">";
                criaDivElementos += "</span>";
                criaDivElementos += "</div>";
                criaDivElementos += "</div>";

                $("#grid_info").append(criaDivElementos);
            },
```

Referência: https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete